# Need to validate USA zip code in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with 2 optional parameters as below. I need to validate one of the optional parameter @Zip i.e. I need to make sure that the user is entering correct USA zip code, when he is executing this stored procedure. I tried using a regular expressions as in the below stored procedure, but it did not work. Please let me know how can I accomplish this? Thank you.

```
                     CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetDetails
                     (
                       @Name varchar(255) = null, @Zip int = null
                      )
                     as
                     begin
         SELECT DISTINCT
         [Name],[Address1],[Address2],[City],[Zip]
         FROM    AddressTable
         WHERE 
             ( @Name IS NULL
                      OR AddressTable.[Name] LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'
                     )
                AND  ( @Zip IS NULL
                     OR AddressTable.[Zip] = (RegexMatch (@Zip, '^\d{5}(\-\d{4})?$'))
                     )
```

Comment: Do you just want to validate that it's in the correct format, or do you want to actually validate that it is a real zip code? Just because it's in 5+4 format doesn't mean it's real. Also I wouldn't be passing that in as an INT... that won't work with 5+4, and it also will drop leading zeroes.

Comment: AFAIK there is no `RegexMatch` function in sql server.R u using `CLR` to use the function ?

Comment: Aaron I passed @Zip as varchar and it worked. Thank you. I am not concerned if it is a real zip code or not, I just want to pull the matching records from my AddressTable.

Comment: Praveen I am not aware of using CLR function. Could you please explain.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SQL Server apparently supports regular expressions according to [this StackOverflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964124/regular-expression-inside-sql-server), but it looks like there's some extreme setup.

Since your procedure accepts `@Zip` as an `INT` type, you only have to check that it's between 0 and 99,999. But that's at odds with your attempted regex, plus I'd recommend using a character type as Aaron points out above.

If `@Zip` is a character type, the SQL Server `LIKE` is robust enough to validate it. This will check if the ZIP is 5 digits or 9 digits or "5 digits plus dash plus four digits":

```
IF   @Zip LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  OR @Zip LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  OR @Zip LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

This will ensure the ZIP is well-formed, but it won't guarantee that the ZIP is actually recognized as valid by the US Postal Service, nor will it guarantee that the ZIP is appropriate to the street address, city and state.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from the excellent answer from Ed Gibbs - if you are going to compare the zip code to a reference table - you need to ensure there are leading zero's stored, and you really only care about the first five digits - you can use something like this:

```
LEFT JOIN DimZipCode dz on REPLICATE('0',5-LEN(LEFT(fia.ZipCode,5))) + LEFT(fia.ZipCode,5)  = dz.ZipCode
```