# Case Statement producing Incorrect Result when Multiple check Occur in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to validate ZIP codes in SQL Server 2012.

Conditions: ZIP should start and end with Number and it should be only 5 and 10 digit; if it is 10 digit than after 5th digit - and end with 4 digit

```
declare @mytab table (zip VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @mytab
    SELECT '54825' UNION ALL
    SELECT '4459' UNION ALL
    SELECT '68523' UNION ALL
    SELECT '57425-2342' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ABC12' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ZR2' UNION ALL
    SELECT '79425-2342' UNION ALL
    SELECT '794252342' UNION ALL
    SELECT '794252342ASWS'

--SELECT * FROM @mytab

SELECT 
    ZIP,
    CASE 
       WHEN LEN(ZIP) = 5 THEN 'VALID'
       WHEN SUBSTRING(ZIP, CHARINDEX('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', ZIP), 5) = ZIP THEN 'VALID'
       WHEN SUBSTRING(ZIP, CHARINDEX('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', ZIP), 10) = ZIP THEN 'VALID'
       ELSE 'INVALID' 
    END AS RES
FROM 
    @mytab
```

Here, `4459, ABC12, ZR2, 794252342` are invalid but are recognized as valid

and

`57425-2342, 79425-2342` are valid but labeled as invalid.

Am I missing anything? Please help.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15629155/62576) will help you.

Comment: Does it need to contain all digits? I mean is `1ABC5-6EF9` valid?

Comment: @SalmanA: yes all digits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're missing is that [`SUBSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) doesn't *reject* invalid index values for *start* that are less than `1`, the first character of the string. That means that

```
SUBSTRING(ZIP,CHARINDEX('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]',ZIP),5)
```

Will return up to the first 4<sup>1</sup> characters of `ZIP` even if it doesn't match the pattern (because [`CHARINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) returns `0` in that case). Similarly for the 10 character version returning up to 9 characters. (I say "up to" because obviously some inputs don't have 4/9 characters)

Just use something like:

```
CASE 
       WHEN ZIP LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' THEN 'VALID'
       WHEN ZIP LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'THEN 'VALID'
       ELSE
       'INVALID' END AS RES
```

---

<sup>1</sup> 1 less than length because:

> If *start* is less than 1, the returned expression will begin at the first character that is specified in expression. In this case, the number of characters that are returned is the largest value of either the sum of *start* + *length* - 1 or 0. If *start* is greater than the number of characters in the value expression, a zero-length expression is returned.

Comment: this not give correct result. 4459 appear as valid, but it is only length 4

Comment: If I take your sample script and substitute the `CASE` in my answer for yours, the row for value `4459` is listed as `INVALID`. I've run it.

Comment: @OMG - of course, it would help if you had also included expected results in your question too. I'm getting `VALID` for `54825`, `68523`, `57425-2342` and `79425-2342` and `INVALID` for all other rows, which I assumed was correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT ZIP,
       (CASE WHEN ZIP LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' THEN 'VALID'
             WHEN ZIP LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' THEN 'VALID'
             ELSE 'INVALID'
        END) as res
THEN 'VALID'
FROM @mytab;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the functions of [REVERSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/reverse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [ISNUMERIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to validate the fields, in the explanation of @Jakub_Ojmucianski, it has an error when validating. (try with 79-4252342)

```
DECLARE @mytab TABLE (zip VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @mytab
    SELECT '79-4252342' UNION ALL
    SELECT '4459' UNION ALL
    SELECT '68523' UNION ALL
    SELECT '57425-2342' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ABC12' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ZR2' UNION ALL
    SELECT '79425-2342' UNION ALL
    SELECT '794252342' UNION ALL
    SELECT '794252342ASWS'

SELECT 
    ZIP,
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(ZIP,1,5)) = 1 AND LEN(ZIP) = 5 
            THEN 'VALID'
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(ZIP,1,5)) = 1 AND LEN(ZIP) = 10 AND ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ZIP),1,4)) = 1
            THEN 'VALID'
    ELSE 'INVALID'
    END AS RES
FROM 
    @mytab
```

Comment: Does have a couple of minor issues because it's still relying on `ISNUMERIC` and doesn't validate the 6th character. `123D5` and `-23D5B4E2+` are both accepted. (As is `$,,,,!,,,£`. Sorry, can't help myself with ones like this. I have to find the worst possible example I can)

Comment: If we read the user's conditions, nowhere does he speak of verifying the sixth character, if he wishes to complement with a better idea, go ahead.. (Conditions: ZIP should start and end with Number and it should be only 5 and 10 digit; if it is 10 digit than after 5th digit - and end with 4 digit)

Comment: They may not have articulated their conditions well in that sentence. The `-` there isn't punctuation in the sentence. It's what the 6th character is required to be. We can also see it by the patterns they've tried to apply in their `CHARINDEX` expressions.