# SQL Server : select column and do regex on it

Tags: sql-server, regex

I am trying to do a select with a regex. I have seen how to do this in where clauses on [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964124/regular-expressions-inside-sql-server) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206404/mssql-regular-expression) but that is not what I want. What I want is to select a column, then apply a regex, then display it as something else (in this case timecodes).

I thought there was a regular expression function, but I only seem to find 
[PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), which just tells me where the pattern starts. Is there a SQL function that I can use to apply a regex to something?

Something like:

```
SELECT PATINDEX('/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/', TIMECODE) AS timecode 
FROM INSTANCE
```

Except it returns the column with the regex applied

**EDIT**

Just so there is more clarity, I want to change how the data is returned. Say I have this time in millis: 1539885525171. I want to have that returned as the time 17:59:29.

I know this regex is not right, but for the sake of an example, I want to apply the expression '/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/' to 1539885525171 so that it returns 17:59:29

Comment: What to do want to mean by "apply a regex"  Can you show us data sample, expected result, and regex rules?

Comment: Full Regex isn't supported in sql server. There are limited similarities with `PATINDEX` and `LIKE`. Sample data and expected output would help determine what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok. See the edit please

Comment: so like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12757846/6167855) ?

Answer (score 0):

If You only need a time You can do this way

```
declare @UTC bigint = 1539885525171 
SELECT convert(nvarchar(8)
             ,DATEADD(MILLISECOND, @UTC % 1000, DATEADD(SECOND, @UTC / 1000, '19700101'))
             ,8)
```

Comment: and even more simple `declare @UTC bigint = 1539885525171 ; SELECT convert(nvarchar(20),  DATEADD(SECOND, @UTC / 1000, '19700101'),8)`